# why angular elements needs to be created in an application but it does not works with a library module?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, custom-element

I was trying to export an angular element to use it in an arbitrary non framework project. You can export everything but nothing really happens when you import the script. But if you follow some guides out there they use a application instead it works, but it is basically a whole angular app running in a webcomponent wrapper. I am trying to bring angular packages and have it loaded as a library, not sure it is even possible.

ex1: https://medium.com/@smarth55/angular-elements-use-them-everywhere-including-your-angular-app-697f8e51e08d

ex2: https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/angular-element-how-to-use-angular-components-in-react-vue-js-93757c92357b

When I exported a similar sample but from a library I can use it within any other angular app. Just by adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA. But importing the custom element to any non framework project nothing happens, the script is loaded but the custom element is blank. Are there extra steps to be able to use angular elements outside of angular that are exported from a lib? I would like to avoid custom builders like ngx-build-plus.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.4/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@9.1.13/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/elements@9.1.13/bundles/elements.umd.js"></script>
  <script src="/my-lib-element/dist/my-lib-elem/bundles/my-lib-elem.umd.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <!-- script runs and is imported without errors but the element below does nothing -->
  <my-elem-cpt></my-elem-cpt>
  <!-- and yes the name is correct but it seems the lib never registers the element in the browser -->
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any clue if this possible?

Comment: Yes, using Frameworks to create Web Components is _kinda_ like including the whole IKEA when you only buy one chair (IMHO)

Comment: I agree. I understand the reasons they do that, I have been in a couple of teams that had this approach. But I would never approve the decision. It is literally one app within another with all the same dependencies. Not really micro frontends but can't do much about it most of the time.